# Qt: accept mouseRelease only when there was no drag and drop

Tags: c++, qt

I have a subclass of QGraphicsView that should accept two kinds of mouse events: drag and drop for scrolling and simple clicks for item selection/highlight.
So I use

```
setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
```

to enable scrolling the view with the "Hand". And I have a function like this:

```
void GraphView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent* e)
{
    if (e->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        emit leftClicked(mapToScene(e->pos()));
    else
        emit rightClicked(mapToScene(e->pos()));
    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}
```

which creates signal whenever the user clicks on the scene.

However, the problem is: when I stop dragging and release the mouse button, the `mouseReleaseEvent` function is called, and if the cursor happens to be over some element of the scene, it will get highlighted.
How can I changed the `mouseReleaseEvent` function so that the signals are created only if there was no previous drag of the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mousePress and mouseMove in combination with mouseRelease, then you can determine what mouse action the user just performed.

If you have mousePress then mouseRelease, then it must be a simple click.
If you have mousePress, mouseMove, and then mouseRelease, then it must be a drag.

The Qt documentation contains an example of interpreting combinations of mouse events in action in a scribbling program.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-scribble-example.html

You can extend the principle to something like this:

```
private bool MyWidget::dragging = false;
private bool MyWidget::pressed = false;


void MyWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        pressed=true;
    }
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event)
}

void MyWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if ((event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) && pressed)
    {
        dragging=true;
    }
    QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event)
}

void MyWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::LeftButton && pressed) {
        pressed = false;
        if (dragging)
        {
            dragging = false;
        }
        else
        {
            // plain mouse click
            // do something here
        }
    }
    QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(event)
}
```

Note that this does not address edge cases where a user's mouse action is performed only partially inside the widget. I must also admit that I am relatively new to Qt and have not yet used ScrollHandDrag, but this is how one would go about identifying a certain combination of mouse events.